# Algebra structure on Haagerup Tensor Product of Operator Spaces

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, operator-algebras, c-star-algebras

> Let $A$ and $B$ be operator spaces. Is there any algebra structure on Haagerup tensor product of operator spaces such that the Haagerup tensor product becomes Banach Algebra?

Any references or ideas?